# Why does Postgres create multiple indexes on the primary key by default?

Tags: postgresql

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/indexes-unique.html): "PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table."

In my table `notifications`, I set the `id` column as the primary key. When I take a look at the indexes on the table using `\d notifications` the output is:

```
Indexes:
    "notifications_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "notifications_unique_id" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
```

Does this mean I have two indexes on the same column? If so - why does PG do this by default?

Also - does this mean that all my indexes should have this constraint?

Comment: How did you create the table? Please show us the ddl.

Comment: Postgres most definitely does **not** create multiple indexes. One of them has been manually created by you. Or you defined the ID column as `unique` in addition it being a primary key.

Comment: did you create it using an ORM?

Comment: Update - this was indeed an oopsie. A coworker had added an `alter table` and added a unique constraint to the primary key column. I'm assuming this is unneeded and adds unnecessary over head because - "PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table"?